# Initialize array with specific amount of elements?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to **initialize** an **array with a specific amount of elements**, without a loop?

```
// Pseudo code
$reviews = array(5);
print_r($reviews);

// outputs 5 empty elements in array
Array ( [0] =>  [1] =>  [2] =>  [3] =>  [4] =>  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways, here's three:

```
$array = array_fill(0, 5, '');

$array[]=$array[]=$array[]=$array[]=$array[]='';

$array = explode(' ', '    ');
```

Comment: Nice creativity over there!

Comment: Bah. Just posted the exact same thing. I definitely need more coffee! +1